# Python - ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using MAC OS Catalina 10.15.3 and using Python 2.7 (just to replicate the old project developed in 2.7).

I already went through the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101488/valueerror-unable-to-configure-handler-file-errno-2-no-such-file-or-direct/60213100#60213100) about "ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

and I am facing the similar problem. I tried to follow the procedure given in the post mentioned above, but it did not solve my problem.

I am following a deployment procedure of a github project (cloud copasi). When I run the instruction (python manage.py migrate) it gives me the following error on zsh terminal. I am running the process inside virtual environment.

I already have the file created in the specified directory but it is still giving me the same error.

I am sorry but I am new to MAC and Python.
Immediate help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/cloudcopasi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/cloudcopasi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/cloudcopasi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/cloudcopasi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/cloudcopasi/log/cloud-copasi.log'
```

Comment: That's a relative path - are you sure Django actually can find the file with this path? Run this command in Django shell and check if it detects file with your path: `os.path.exists(path)` (import `os` module first)

Comment: Make sure the directory `/home/cloudcopasi/log/` exists and the user running django has write permissions for that folder and file