# File access issues with django and gunicorn

Tags: django

I’m wondering how file permissions work on Django. I have created a file debug.log where I want my logging to output. Its permissions look like this
`-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      0 Apr  3 19:16 debug.log` 
I have a Django superuser called ubuntu who I think should have rw access to this file based on what [this](https://linuxize.com/post/understanding-linux-file-permissions/) says. 
However, when I run systemctl status gunicorn, I get

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 570, in configure
raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file'
```

Which according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101488/valueerror-unable-to-configure-handler-file-errno-2-no-such-file-or-direct)
Should mean that either the file doesn’t exist, or my user doesn’t have access.
The filename has value
`os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'debug.log')`. And if I print that value out, I get `/home/ubuntu/ACE/rangr/debug.log` which is where the debug.log file is. Does anyone know why my django user doesn't have access to debug.log or why django thinks the file doesn't exist?

Comment: A Django user does not play a role here. You must ensure that the UNIX user running gunicorn can write to the log file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add I have the following in my gunicorn.service file  

`[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/ACE/rangr`  

I think this should mean the UNIX user ubuntu also has access